# Upload ASP.net website to a hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, web

I finish creating my website using Visual Studio 2010.. also I already have a domain name... My question is **how do I publish/upload my website to my domain through the FTP server**... I'm a total newbie at this and web tutorials are so complicated It makes my brain bleed...

I already tried using copy website but my website fails to appear on my domain... instead only my scripts/ ".aspx files" and resources appear on the page... in hyperlink format...

I also tried to publish the website but the same happened...

Comment: blind guess: you sure you are using an ASP.NET supported web server, such as IIS ? ( Make sure .NET version is correct )

Comment: You might have to go to your host's control panel and turn on ASP.Net

Comment: Who is hosting the site? Do they support APS.NET?

Comment: Cpanel Inc. is hosting my site

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have 2 choices most likely. One is going to be some sort of ftp (or secure ftp). The other would be web deploy if the host offers it. What you want to do is publish your project to your local file system and then copy THAT output to the ftp (www) root (most likely). If you have web deploy you can also set that up in the publish settings in visual studio. Your web host should be able to provide the info you need in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you need to publish your project to iis. make sure your iis is activated first in your machine, and initialize your asp framework with the iis. after all the setup are complete, then you can publish your project.